# error: I'm trying to display categories names from category table in product page dropdown, but displaying undefined variable, please help me out

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**model**
here is the model where I'm selecting category name from the category table

```
public function getcategorylist()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT category_name FROM category');
        return $this->db->query($query)->result();
    }
```

**controller**

```
public function getcategorylists()
{
    $this->load->model('delivery_model');
    $data['displatcat'] = $this->Category_model->getcategorylist();
    $this->load->view('addevent', $data);
}
```

**view**

```
<select class="form-control">
 <?php foreach($displatcat as $categories){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $categories->category_name; ?>"><?php echo $categories->category_name; ?></option>';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The view code snippet has an error on the 3rd line ';

Answer (score 0):

The controller one. Just return it like this :

```
return $query->result();
```